# C++//NumericQuestion

Tags: c++

I'm a begginer when it comes to C++.

I have to write a program that asks a question and I give the answer than it checks if it's right or wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Question
{
public:
       Question();

       void set_text(string question_text);
       void set_answer(string correct_response);
       bool check_answer(string response) const;
       void display() const;

private:
        string text;
        string answer;
};

Question::Question()
{
}    

void Question::set_text(string question_text)
{
     text = question_text;
}

void Question::set_answer(string correct_response)
{
     answer = correct_response;
}

bool Question::check_answer(string response) const
{
     return response == answer;    
}

void Question::display() const
{
     cout << text << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string response;
    cout << boolalpha;

    Question q1;
    q1.set_text("Who was the inventor of  C ++ ? " );
    q1.set_answer("Bjarne Stroustrup" );

    q1.display();
    cout << " Your answer is :  " ;
    getline(cin,response);
    cout << q1.check_answer(response) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is it requires also for me to add a class for NumericalQuestion that checks if there's more than  0.01 difference between response and expected answer. And this is where I'm getting my difficulties.
If someone can show me how it can be done or give me some tips I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Look at the different data types C++ has. Comparing a difference of 0.01 is easy with one or two of them. Also, this is homework I assume?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `NumericalQuestion` class and tell us the diffculties you are having with it?

Comment: Yes it is,i managed to write all the other tasks in this thing except the part with the numeric question =/.

Comment: Are you struggling with converting an answer from string type to a numeric type or the 0.01 comparing?

Comment: This is the problem.I can't write the code for NumericalQuestion at all.I can't even figure out where to start :x

Comment: What you have there is a good start for `NumericalAnswer`. All you have to do is change a couple things really. With a numerical question you could get rid of the `set_answer` function as well, since C++ can do math.

Comment: Im struggling with both i think.Though i belive i can convert it from string to numeric if i hit my head against wall for awhile,bu the 0.01 comparing is whats bugging me.

Comment: Do you have to use a string to store the answer/response?

Comment: But the set_answer function is part of what i have to write,so i'll keep it.

Comment: No i can use whatever means,its not specified.

Comment: @IzordIzrodski: If I assume you have `float` as the types for `answer` and `response` in `NumericalQuestion` class, then you can simple do `return fabs(response - answer) < 0.01`.

Comment: @Asha, `text` is still the question so it'd make sense as a string.

Comment: @Asha i didn't quite understand what you meant =/.

Comment: @Chris: Oops..updated comment.

Comment: A `float` (or another type) can hold decimals, whereas `int` can only hold whole numbers. Using decimals, you can compare the 0.01 difference you need. `fabs` can do that for you a bit more quickly.

Comment: @chris so thats basically a function that will change my string values into floating point and by that i'll be able to compare them?

Comment: The point is to not use a string in the first place to hold the answer. C++ has 2 data types designed for handling **numbers** like 0.01, just like `int` is designed for numbers like 5 or 8.

Comment: Oh i see,then im gonna try doing it now.

Comment: A function that you might find useful is atof, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/

Comment: Are you overloading your functions, or just creating similar functions w/ different names?

Answer (score 1):

I'll not write the complete code as it looks like homework to me. Let's say you have a class called `NumericalQuestion`. Now, since you want to work with decimal point numbers the type of the `answer` variable needs to `float` (or `double`). In that case you need to convert the string read from console into a float and set it into this object as the expected response. Once the user enters the answer, you need to again convert it to `float` and call `check_answer`. Inside `check_answer` you need to compare whether the difference between the answer and the expected answer is less than 0.01 or not. You can achieve this by doing `return fabs(answer - response) < 0.01`.